# Fixing size of div to make it scrollable without expanding the entire view

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a screen in my React App that serves as an Overview where a list should display all created accounts. But I want a button fixed at the bottom and the account list scrollable in the area that is not taken by the header elements and the bottom button. So it should fill the entire screen but only the list should be scrollable.
I tried with flex-grow but it did not seem to work...Thanks for your help!

```css
.list {
  overflow: scroll
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>some Header</header>
  <p>Some description</p>
  <div class="list">
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
  </div>
  <button>Some button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `scroll` instead of `scrollable`. Also a `max-height` for list:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 20px;
}

.list {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 50vh;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <p>some Header</p>
    <p>Some description</p>
  </header>

  <div class="list">
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
    <p>Some value</p>
  </div>
  <button>Some button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes the list itself as big as the screen...The rest of the page should stick. With 100vh it still overflows at the bottom...

Comment: @Kilian Hi. I edited my answer. please check. do you want it?